# Relatively defined dates for movable holidays in NodaTime

Tags: date, nodatime

[NodaTime](http://nodatime.org) has [`AnnualDate`](http://nodatime.org/2.2.x/api/NodaTime.AnnualDate.html) that can be used to represent a date for recurring events, e.g. birth dates or anniversaries. `AnnualDate` does, however, require that the date is the same each year.

Is there a way to specify an annual date in relative terms, such as "the first Sunday in June", "the second to last Monday in January", "the Sunday before May 3rd", or "the third Wednesday in September"? This would be beneficial for things like movable holidays and such.

Comment: Since working days are basically the inverse of the holidays, I consider this the same question as the duplicate.  Basically, the answer is no, but be sure to check the post I linked to in the comments on that dup.